# Excel formula for "result of 2-7 on the die is always treated as if you rolled an 8"

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet program which rolls twenty-sided dice. Sheet 1 is Rolls and Sheet 2 is Values.

I want to roll a d20, but if it comes up 2-7, fudge it and assume I got 8 instead.

`Rolls!A2`'s function is `=RANDBETWEEN(1,20)` which returns a random number between 1 and 20 to represent the d20 roll. `Values!7E` is function which calculates a (non-random) number (currently 13).

Currently, `Rolls!C7`'s function attempts to calculate my result with `=Values!E7+Rolls!A2`. But I would like to update `Rolls!C7` to reflect the fudging. If `Rolls!A2` returns numbers 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or 7, `Rolls!C7` would instead be calculated as if it rolled an 8.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you could probably use a nested IF: =IF(Rolls!A2>1,IF(Rolls!A2<=7,8, Rolls!A2),1). This will return 1 if you roll a 1, 8 if you roll 2-7 or 8 or more if you roll 8 or more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `Rolls!A2` in your formula with this: `IF(AND(Rolls!A2<8, Rolls!A2>1),8,Rolls!A2)` this way it will always be at least 8 unless a 1 is rolled.

Comment: It works! ([picture!](http://kunigunda.tumblr.com/post/31673182985/exceptional-skill-excel)) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do `=IF(Rolls!A2=1,1,MAX(Rolls!A2,8))`

Comment: If you add an explanation to your answer as @Daniel did to his, maybe it can be upvoted. Presently you require whoever is reading this to run it themselves to see how it works.